# Why can't I login to my Geometry Dash account on my tablet (kindle fire)?

Tags: geometry-dash

I can login to my account on my laptop but not my tablet? Is there a reason why? Every time I try to log in on my tablet it says invalid, but I use the same info to log in on the computer and it works. Why is this?

Comment: If your geometry dash updated?

Answer (score -1):

It could be a range of problems:

- You could be using a different (worse) Internet connection
- You could just be messing up your typing
- Your tablet keyboard could be on a wrong setting/different language
- You might just have Caps Lock on....

One of those might be your problem.